# Dynamic Routing structure NEXT JS

Tags: next.js, url-routing

There are 3 pages for which there are dynamic routes

1. Search Page `/buy/properties-in-navi-mumbai-mumbai`
2. Property Details Page `/buy/marathon-nexzone-property-panvel-mumbai-218`
3. HomePage `/buy/pune`

**Note:-** The string after the `/buy` is dynamic

Now I know that NEXT JS follows **folder based routing**.

*My Question :-* How will I know which page (and in that case which component) should be rendered ?

*My Naive Approach :-* Have a common identifier like

`buy/search/properties-in-navi-mumbai-mumbai`

`buy/property/marathon-nexzone-property-panvel-mumbai-218`

> but this won't solve the problem for homepage as homepage has the url
> containing simply the domain name `https:example.com` plus, when the
> user selects module type (buy,rent) and city name from the dropdown in
> Homepage then the url changes to `buy/cityName` where `cityName` is
> dynamic and this is a url for Homepage. So how will I know that it is
> which page

My folder structure is as follows

```
pages/
├─ buy/
│  ├─ search/
│  │  ├─ [id].js
│  ├─ [id].js
│  ├─ property/
│  │  ├─ [id].js
├─ index.js
```

*Issue with my Approach :-* The issue I am having with my solution is that the urls would get changed and the initial mentioned urls have already been crawled so this would affect the site's SEO as we will have to route these crawled URLs to something like `401` and the newly created URLs need to crawled again which would take time is not feasible with the business requirement currently.

I need help with the issue in my approach any help is much appreciated Thank You.

Comment: Can the slug be used to determine what component should be rendered?

Comment: @juliomalves No is there any other approach ?